# No me muestra la consulta de la llave foranea con query builder y vuejs en laravel

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vue.js

Tengo el inconveniente en pintar en una tabla los datos de una consulta.

esta es la tabla que esta relacionada con la persona y que intento pintar en la vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el archivo Modelo **Proveedor.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Proveedor extends Model
{
    //se hace referencia la table de este modelo ya que lo hicimos en español es diferente el nombre
    protected $table='proveedores';

    protected $fillable=['id','contacto','telefono_contacto'];

    //colocamos la propieda timestamp falso ya que en la tabla no la necesitamos
    public $timestamps=false;

    //funcion que explica que provedor pertenece a una persona
    public function persona(){
        return $this.belongsTo('App\Persona');
    }
}
```

este es el archivo modelo **Persona.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Persona extends Model
{
    //campos de la tabla que van a recibir valor
    protected $fillable=['nombre','tipo_documento','direccion','telefono','email'];

    //una persona esta relacionada con un solo proveedor
    public function proveedor(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Proveedor');
    }
}
```

este es el archivo de las rutas **web.php**

```
Route::get('/proveedor', 'ProveedorController@index');
Route::post('/proveedor/registrar', 'ProveedorController@store');
Route::put('/proveedor/actualizar', 'ProveedorController@update');
```

este es el archivo controlador **ProveedorController.php**

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use App\Proveedor;
use App\Persona;

class ProveedorController extends Controller
{
     public function index(Request $request)
    {
        //si no son peticiones ajax dirigirlo a la ruta raiz
        if(!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');

        $buscar=$request->buscar;
        $criterio=$request->criterio;

        if($buscar==''){
            //se une table personas con provedores con su id
            $personas=Proveedor::join('personas','proveedores.id','=','personas.id')
            ->select('personas.id','personas.nombre','personas.tipo_documento',
            'personas.num_documento','personas.direccion','personas.telefono',
            'personas.email','proveedores.contacto','proveedores.telefono_contacto')
            ->orderBy('personas.id','desc')->paginate(3);
        }
        else{
            $personas=Proveedor::join('personas','proveedores.id','=','personas.id')
            ->select('personas.id','personas.nombre','personas.tipo_documento',
            'personas.num_documento','personas.direccion','personas.telefono',
            'personas.email','proveedores.contacto','proveedores.telefono_contacto')
            ->where('personas.'.$criterio, 'like', '%'. $buscar . '%')
            ->orderBy('personas.id','desc')->paginate(3);
        }

        $personas = Proveedor::paginate(2);

        return[
            'pagination'=>[
            "total" => $personas->total(),
            "per_page" =>$personas->perPage(),
            "current_page" =>$personas->currentPage(),
            "last_page" =>$personas->lastPage(),
            "from" =>$personas->firstItem(),
            "to" =>$personas->lastItem(),
            ],
            'personas'=>$personas
        ];
    }
```

este es el archivo componente vuejs **Proveedor.vue**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Opciones</th>
                                    <th>Nombre</th>
                                    <th>Tipo Documento</th>
                                    <th>Numero</th>
                                    <th>Direccion</th>
                                    <th>Telefono</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Contacto</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr v-for="persona in arrayPersona" :key="persona.id">
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" @click="abrirModal('persona','actualizar',persona)" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">
                                          <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td v-text="persona.nombre"></td>
                                    <td v-text="persona.tipo_documento"></td>
                                    <td v-text="persona.num_documento"></td>
                                    <td v-text="persona.direccion"></td>
                                    <td v-text="persona.telefono"></td>
                                    <td v-text="persona.email"></td>
                                    <td v-text="persona.contacto"></td>
                                </tr>                                
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <nav>
                            <ul class="pagination">
                                <li class="page-item" v-if="pagination.current_page > 1">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#" @click.prevent="cambiarPagina(pagination.current_page - 1,buscar,criterio)">Ant</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="page-item" v-for="page in pagesNumber" :key="page" :class="[page == isActived ? 'active' : '']">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#" @click.prevent="cambiarPagina(page,buscar,criterio)" v-text="page"></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="page-item" v-if="pagination.current_page < pagination.last_page">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#" @click.prevent="cambiarPagina(pagination.current_page + 1,buscar,criterio)">Sig</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
<script>
    export default {
        data (){
            return {
                persona_id: 0,
                nombre : '',
                tipo_documento : 'DNI',
                num_documento:'',
                direccion:'',
                telefono:'',
                email:'',
                contacto:'',
                telefono_contacto:'',
                arrayPersona : [],
                modal : 0,
                tituloModal : '',
                tipoAccion : 0,
                errorPersona : 0,
                errorMostrarMsjPersona : [],
                pagination : {
                    'total' : 0,
                    'current_page' : 0,
                    'per_page' : 0,
                    'last_page' : 0,
                    'from' : 0,
                    'to' : 0,
                },
                offset : 3,
                criterio : 'nombre',
                buscar : ''
            }
        },
 methods : {
            listarPersona (page,buscar,criterio){
                let me=this;
                var url= '/proveedor?page=' + page + '&buscar='+ buscar + '&criterio='+ criterio;
                axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
                    var respuesta= response.data;
                    me.arrayPersona = respuesta.personas.data;
                    me.pagination= respuesta.pagination;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
</script>
```

solo me imprime los datos que no esta relacionada con la tabla persona
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: quita el `$personas = Proveedor::paginate(2);` antes del return en el controlador. Con esa línea estas pisando el resultado de la consulta que tiene los joins

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Si, tienes toda la razón.

Comment: Recuerda borrar la entrada en meta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4638/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta fue la que me comento el usuario porloscerros y fue la siguiente:

quitar el

```
 $personas = Proveedor::paginate(2);
```

antes del return en el controlador. Con esa línea estas pisando el resultado de la consulta que tiene los joins

Comment: Pues no olvides marcarla como aceptada

Comment: Si pero me toca esperar dos dias habiles ya que fui yo que coloque la respuesta. Si lo fueras colocado en respuesta y no en comentario ya la fuera colocado.